# Table background color change with values stored in a PHP array

Tags: php

I am trying to change the cell background color of a HTML table using mysql values stored in a php variable named $mp.

This is the code:

```
$res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM contact");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
    $mp= $row['id'];
}
mysql_free_result($res);

switch ($mp){
    case 37:
        $DBNUsers->setTableCellStyle('TDC','','');
        break;
    case 67:
        $DBNUsers->setTableCellStyle('','TD','headerTD');
        break;
    default:
        $DBNUsers->setTableCellStyle('TD','','headerTD');
        break;
}
```

1. `$DBNUsers->setTableCellStyle('','','');` is a user defined function and it is working properly to change the color of the whole HTML table
2. But I want to change the color of a relevant row that is matching with the `id` stored in an array.  I have used switch - case block. Only working the default function `$DBNUsers->setTableCellStyle('TD','','headerTD');` correctly.
3. When I use echo it outputs the `id`s as `37,67,70,102,105,124,125,136,138,....` But I used `37,67 ......` for the case constructor it is not changed the relevant row color.

Anyone can help me?

Comment: You'll need to give more info on what setTableCellStyle does.

Comment: setTableCellStyle function coloured the background of a HTML table in my project. TD, TDC and headerTD is the names of CSS classes.

Answer (score 0):

What ever I get from your question, I posted as below it can be help full to You

```
<table border="1" id="mytable" name="mytable">
  <?php for($i=0;$i<3;$i++) { ?>
  <tr id='<?php echo $i; ?>'>
  <td>
      test
  </td>
  </tr>
<?php  } ?>
</table>
<script type="text/javascript">
var t = document.getElementById("mytable");
var trs = t.getElementsByTagName("tr");
for (var i=0; i<trs.length; i++)
{
  t.getElementsByTagName("tr")[0].style.backgroundColor='lightblue';
  t.getElementsByTagName("tr")[1].style.backgroundColor='green';
  t.getElementsByTagName("tr")[2].style.backgroundColor='yellow';

}
</script>
```